# Showing that $e^z=z$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

One of our review problems for my complex analysis final is the following:

> Show that $e^z=z$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

I've seen a few solutions online, but none of them have used material that was covered in our introductory complex analysis course. Would anyone be able to provide a simple solution?

I'm trying to think of ways to invoke bounding in some way but I can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: Maybe I've found a solution only using the residue theorem and some (rather easy) bounds.

Answer (score 12):

From page 5 of [this book](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/grads/clungstr/complex_analysis/pset8.pdf) :

> By Picard’s big theorem and a previous example in the book, we know $e^z$ has an essential
>   singularity at infinity, hence so does $f(z) = e^z − z$. This implies that as $|z| → ∞$, we know
>   $f(z)$ takes on all values infinitely many times with the possible exception of one point. This
>   point could still be zero; however $f(z + 2πi) = f(z) − 2πi$. Therefore, we know $f(z)$ takes
>   on at least one of ${0, 2πi}$ infinitely many times, hence has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Very elegant proof.

Comment: If we throw big Picard at it, I prefer looking at $z\cdot e^{-z}$. It has a single zero, hence it attains the value $1$ infinitely often.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k\geq 1$ and let $\log_k$ be the branch of $\log$ that maps the upper half plane onto the strip $H_k = \{z \mid 2k\pi < \operatorname{Im}(z) < (2k+1)\pi\}$.  Then $\log_k$ is a contraction mapping of $\overline{H}_k$ (since $|\log_k'| \leq (2k \pi)^{-1}<1$ on that closed strip).  Therefore $\log_k$ has a single [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem) $z_k \in \overline{H}_k$.  Clearly $\exp(z_k)=z_k$.